# Google play store - This item is not compatible with your device

Tags: android, google-play

For some reason, I can compile my android app and email myself the .APK file and install it.   So then i submitted my app to the Google Play market.   Now, for some reason, the google play store says "This item is not compatible with your device.".   Why does it say this if I can actually install via .APK to my phone?  What must I do to tell Google Play that the app is indeed compatible with my device?

Some of my friends have no problem installing my app via google play store.  But some others also have the same issue as me, where they can install via my .APK file but not via the google play store.

What did I do wrong?

The manifest file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.hello20.controller.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hello20.controller.EventListing"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_event_listing"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hello20.controller.Conference"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_conference"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hello20.controller.ConferenceSignin"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_conference_signin"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hello20.controller.Etiquette"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_etiquette"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hello20.controller.MakeCall"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_make_call"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.hello20.library.IncomingCallReceiver"
        android:label="Call Receiver" >
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.hello20.controller.CallScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_call_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hello20.controller.CallHistory"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_call_history" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hello20.controller.WebViewer"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_web_viewer" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

### UPDATE

here is the link to the app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hello20&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5oZWxsbzIwIl0.

As you can see, nothing is enabled... we at least not for me. I have four devices available to my account. They are as follows:

1. Galaxy S3: 4.2.2
2. Galaxy Tab 10.1: 4.1.2 (I think)
3. Galaxy Tab 7 first version: 4.2.2
4. Galaxy S2 LTE: 4.x.x. (Don't know because it's my wifes)

ADDITIONAL NOTES

WHen we remove all of the `uses-feature` elements from the manifest file, compile and upload, then the app is supported by all devices.  If even one of the `uses-feature` element is in the manifest file, then it's not support by any devices. So what is the proper way to use the `uses-feature` element in the manifest file?

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: My Device is galaxy note Bell Samsung SGH-I717R

Comment: *What did I do wrong?* - You forgot to supply us with any specifics. You can't expect us to guess the contents of the manifest, any app settings when you published the application, and your device model.

Comment: Have you tried lowering the minimum SDK if it isn't necessary?

Comment: We need that version of SDK. I can't remember which permission or code needed it. Either way, I'm running 4.2.2 on an S3. I have deployed to my phone multiple times, and also I've deployed to my Galaxy Tab 10.1 running 4.1.2 (I think). Both were successful, but on the app store it shows nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but is it possible that the device in question cannot support the features that this app has?

Comment: Two devices on my list are able to. I have the software installed on my phone currently which is odd. I'm sure we're missing a step in the manifest file, but I just don't know what it could be. Also, the app uses LinearLayouts, so all the controls will flow accordingly to the screen.

Comment: I haven't been on the dev console in a while, but isn't there an option that allows you to select which devices can use the app?

Comment: Hmm...JOhnathanKong and I rae working together.  I looked in the dev cosole and it says 0 devices supported.  I looked in the list of phones and there's an X beside all the phone models.  So that means no one actually installed the app from the market.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We ended up removing all the `uses-feature` nodes, and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Rather than removing them, it would make more sense to flag them as not required, unless your application really, really can't function properly without the feature.

Answer (score 3):

```
android.hardware.sip.voip
```

Is not listed here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html
So, it seems, that you declared that hoyr app require non existing hardware feature.

Try to use

```
android.software.sip.voip
```

instead

Comment: This was caused by a typo in the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html#manifest

Comment: Google tutorials in general are not the best quality source of information. It's good to check reference when writing code based on those examples.

Comment: We tried piotrpo suggestion but it still didn't work. The only way tto make things work was to remove ALL `uses-feature` elements from our manifest.

Comment: One more suggestion - try to remove those lines, then add it one again from keyboard - sometimes white spaces makes the mess. Particularly if you paste those lines from a www page.